# Handling negative numbers with bit manipulation

Tags: algorithm, go, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to solve this leetcode challenge [Majority Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/).
An array of integers `nums` is given, and it always contains **at least** `len(nums)/2+1` element, the rest of the elements are random. The task is to return the majority element.

I am trying to solve this challenge with the help of bit manipulation and got a working solution, which works on non-negative integers (see the code and the output of tests below). On negative numbers, it returns absolute value of the negative answer.

What am I missing here?

My current code is the following:

```golang
func majorityElement(nums []int) int {
    var bits [32]int // hash of bits

    // for every number
    for _, num := range nums {
        // reading whether a bit is one for each register
        for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
            // if yes, incrementing the counter in hash
            if num&(1<<i) > 0 {
                bits[i] += 1
            }
        }
    }


    result := 0
    // restoring the majority number bit by bit back
    for i := range bits {
        // if the majority of ones => it's a 1, else 0 and do nothing
        if bits[i] > len(nums)/2 { // 1
            result |= 1 << i
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

It produces the following results:

```
true: want 3, got 3 for [3 2 3]
true: want 4, got 4 for [4 5 4]
true: want 2, got 2 for [2 2 1 1 1 2 2]
true: want 4, got 4 for [4 5 4]
false: want -2147483648, got 2147483648 for [-2147483648]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `result` is automatically being considered as `int64`. The reason for this might be that the judge which compiles and runs your code is a 64 bit machine([know more here](https://golangbyexample.com/go-size-range-int-uint/)).

To avoid this we can first convert our result to `int32` and then cast back to `int` as its the required return type

```golang
    return int(int32(result))
```

or you can instead declare, `result` as `int32` and typecast it to `int` while returning

```golang
    var result int32

    // .....

    return int(result)
```

Further explanation:

- for simplicity, let us consider `int8` data type
- All the possibles values have 8 bits
- The maximum positive value is 127(binary representation: 01111111)
- Now try adding 1 to 127, it becomes -128!(binary representation: 10000000)
- Why? In order to represent the negative values in signed datatypes, we always set the left-most(also known as most-significant) bit to 1.

```
10000001 represents -128 + 1 = -127
10000010 represents -128 + 2 = -126
10000011 represents -128 + 3 = -125
...
11111110 represents -128 + 126 = -2
11111111 represents -128 + 127 = -1
```

- The main take away here is that all negative integers have the left-most i.e, most-significant bit set to 1
- now when you represent 128 i.e, the binary number 10000000 in `int16`, it becomes 0000000010000000.
- In 16 bit integer, the most significant bit is not set to 1 for 128, so its not a negative number
- You can try to go through each point using `int32` as the data type and 2147483648(binary representation: 1 followed by 31 zeroes) as the value

Comment: It worked. Can you possibly elaborate on the root cause of that? Is the bit manipulation working differently on int64 as opposed to int32?

Comment: I'll try to add the explanation a while later, but the reason this happens is related to most significant bit being on for negative integers [a part of this video might help a little to better understand](https://youtu.be/QZwneRb-zqA). look from 12 minute mark

Comment: @IvanD added the explanation, let me know if anything is not clear

Comment: Fantastic, abolutely crystal clear now! The mos5 significant bit in int32 was in my case just a bit and lost its meaning.